# Check if sum is possible

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms

Given a range $[L,R]$ I need to find weather a sum $S$ can be made by taking any number between this range i.e $L, L+1, L+2,\dotsc, R$ any number of times

EXAMPLE: If $S=5$ and $L=2$ and $R=3$ then here answer will be " Yes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking $n$ numbers, you can get everything from $nL$ to $nR$  The range of interest of $n$ is $\lfloor \frac SL \rfloor$ to $\lceil \frac SR \rceil$.  Not too many to check.

Comment: What u mean by  range of interest of n?

Comment: With fewer or more numbers you are guaranteed not to be able to get to $S$